# Travis CI: How to generate .travis/deploy_key.pem key for the deployment to remote server

Tags: git, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

As mentioned in the custom deployment page on Travis CI

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/#Git

```
after_success:
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" #start the ssh agent
  - chmod 600 .travis/deploy_key.pem # this key should have push access
  - ssh-add .travis/deploy_key.pem
  - git remote add deploy DEPLOY_REPO_URI_GOES_HERE
  - git push deploy
```

How do I generate `.travis/deploy_key.pem` key?

Is it something which I should set as an env variable?

My GitHub repo is public and I am trying to deploy the app on [Upcloud](https://www.upcloud.com/) platform. Since Upcloud is not pre supported by TravisCI I need to use `after_success` step.

Here is my `travis.yml` file looks so far

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
os:
  - linux
script:
  - yarn test
after_script:
  # Custome upcloud script should go here. More info https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/
  # For encrypting keys: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/
notifications:
  slack:
    on_failure: always
```

Comment: Are you trying to push your built code to a git repo on your Upcloud server? Or are you trying to push your built code back to a GitHub repo?

Comment: Git repo to upcloud server

Comment: What is listening / running on the Upcloud server that you can use to deploy to? Do you have a git repo on there with a deployment user set up? Or want to deploy the built files from Travis to the Upcloud server using rsync or similar?